# Finding difference in code with eclipse and Bitbucket

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, bitbucket

I am new to bitbucket. Previously I have worked with SVN and it's quite simple to use.

How can I check the changes which I am committing in bitbucket and revert/edit on the same screen.

Currently I am using teams> synchronise and commit option, it shows me changes then I have to go in code and edit it manually.

Is there any similar functionality available same as SVN where you can check the changes in code and edit into the same screen

Sorry in advance for any typo error....

Comment: What you did in SVN in the _Team Synchronizing_ perspective, you do now in Git in the _Git Staging_ view. Note that SVN and Git best practices are very different, so it doesn't make sense to look for an one-to-one equivalent way of working.